# How to perform a redirect and pass on data?

Tags: plugin-development, controller

I have a [Controller Action](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers#posting-to-controller-actions) which should pass on some data from one (CP) template to another:

1. Template 1 (`plugin/form`): Form sends data
2. Controller redirects data to Template 2
3. Template 2 (`plugin/`): Shows data

I don't want to just load the template but redirect to `plugin/` and show the data, any ideas?

```php
public function actionTemplate()
{
    $data = 'Something';
    $this->redirect( 'plugin_handle' ); //Pass on $data to 'plugin/'
}
```

**Edit 1:**

Or is there a way to send a post-request to a "route" rather then an actionController?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest either using query parameters in your redirect method, or storing it in session variables (which should be no different than regular PHP).

Comment: Hoped to avoid that, but thanks :)